# foreach overwriting each iteration of messages data php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am getting the contents of mySQL data for messages, then I'm sorting through it per user to create a general array of messages.

IDEA Like So:

```
 Array(
    ["Mr.EasyBB"] => Array(
                    [0] => array(//message data here)
                    [1] => array(//message data here)
                    ...
                  );
 );
```

PHP so far

```
 $messages = $controller->loadResult(
     "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from_username='$username' AND from_uid='$uid'"
     );
 if($messages){
    foreach($messages as $data){
       $to_username = strtolower($data["to_username"]);
          if(!in_array($to_username,$conversations)){
              $conversations[$to_username] = array();
          } 
         $conversations[$to_username][]= $data;
    }
```

Though my output is

```
 Array
 (
  [ianbruce] => Array
      (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 231
                [to_uid] => 231
                [1] => 0001
                [from_uid] => 0001
                [2] => IanBruce
                [to_username] => IanBruce
                [3] => Mr.EasyBB
                [from_username] => Mr.EasyBB
                [4] => n
                [deleted] => n
                [5] => n
                [sent_deleted] => n
                [6] => Howdy Again my Friend
                [message] => Howdy Again my Friend
                [7] => 2014-10-18 00:01:04
                [to_timestamp] => 2014-10-18 00:01:04
                [8] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [from_timestamp] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [9] => y
                [from_seen] => y
                [10] => n
                [to_seen] => n
            )
        )
    )
```

Now I know it's overwriting either the array inside the user or it's overwriting the user altogether making it show the last push of the array. Not sure what I did wrong here, and thought maybe a fresh pair of eyes will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the use of `in_array()`. That function checks for a *value* to be set in an array and not a *key*.

You need to replace this:

```
if(!in_array($to_username,$conversations)){
```

with something like this:

```
if(!isset($conversations[$to_username])){
```

You can also use functions like `key_exists()`, etc. but you probably don't need this condition at all as you can set `$conversations[$to_username][]` even when `$conversations[$to_username]` does not exist.

Comment: knew i was missing something :D